# Show that $S_n$ is a martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, martingales

Consider a random walk $S_n=S_0+\sum^b_{i=1}X_i$ with i.i.d steps $X_i$ taking value $4$ and $-7$ with probabilities $\frac{7}{11}$ and $\frac{4}{11}$ respectively.

I would like to show that $S_n$ is a martingale.

My attempt:

$E[X]=(4)\frac{7}{11}+(-7)\frac{4}{11}$

$E[S_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=E[S_n+X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=S_n+E[X]=S_n$

Where it was used that $X_i$ are iid random variables.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you, could you check this as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222913/how-do-i-determine-the-expected-duration-of-the-walk-until-absorption-at-either